# Writing axis into scientific notation

Tags: plotting, formatting, labeling

I want to express numbers on the y-axis using scientific notation for the plot given below.

```
Plot[-(1/ (m^4)), {m, -0.5, 0.5}, PlotStyle -> {Black, Dashed, Thick},
  LabelStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Arial", Black, FontSize -> 10], 
  AxesLabel -> {Style["x", 20], Style["y", 20]}]
```

I have read the previous post [Scientific notation for the axes of a Plot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/149743/scientific-notation-for-the-axes-of-a-plot), in which it is discussed a correlated doubt. However, the point that is not clear is how to adjust the parameter values for my case of study, as well as, what should be the best values to consider.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Ticks -> {Automatic, Table[{i, ScientificForm@i}, {i, -40000, 0., 10000.}]}` is one possibility.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax in use in that other question is:

```
{#, ScientificForm@#} & /@ Range[min_value, max_value, increment]
```

where `min_value` is the lower bound of the axis, `max_value` is the upper bound, and `increment` is the spacing between successive labeled tick marks.  In your case, a setting of `min_value` of -40000, `max_value` of 0, and `increment` of 10000 gives reasonable results.

Comment: Thanks for commenting @Michael Seifert!