# Logarithmic display in plot axis

Tags: plotting, charts, style, logarithmic-scale

Consider the code

```
dataBC = 10^(RandomReal[6, 10]);
dataTotal = dataBC = 10^(RandomReal[6, 10]);
BoxWhiskerChart[{dataBC, dataTotal}, {"Mean"}, ScalingFunctions -> "Log"]
```

[image]

Is it possible to force the y-axis ticks to be labeled in the form $10^x$ so that, for example, $100$ and $1000$ are shown as $10^2$ and $10^3$, respectively?

Comment: [Search the site for "scientific notation" and "axis"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=scientific+notation+axis). You would find [Writing axis into scientific notation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/253702/27951), [Scientific notation for the axes of a Plot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/149743/27951). Those would also lead to [About the number format in ticks](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5369/27951), which is probably most directly relevant to you.

Comment: [241982](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/241982/use-custom-ticks-on-frameticks-on-loglogplot-but-preserving-the-log-tick-marks).

Comment: log box-whisker plots tend to deceive the reader into thinking there's a lot more probability mass in the lower quartile and a lot less in the top than there really is.

Comment: @flinty I see. Do you have any better suggestion to show data that contains different orders of magnitudes?

Comment: @samwolfe I'd group the data according to order of magnitude and only look at aggregates per group, or I'd try to nest the data in an interactive visualization like a tree map, but there's generally little hope for good visual depictions of such data. In this case you have to ask yourself what benefit a visualization even brings. The trouble with taking a mean (like the middle bar) across 5 orders of magnitude is that it's very much 'mean'ingless. The variance of the data is far more significant here than the mean - _"Never cross a river that is on average 4 feet deep!"_